# JPQL group by having count(*)

Tags: java, jpa, repository, jpql

I have a strange problem with my JQPL queries. I got bookmarks and tags, those two have a many to many relationship, set up via a join table. Now I want to query all bookmarks which have all tags.

**The following works.** It gives me that one bookmark I know it should return.

`@Query("select b from Bookmark b left join b.tags t where t.id in ('mtb', 'video', 'news') group by b.id having count(*) = 3")
Collection<Bookmark> findByTagsStatic();`

Now I am trying to parameterise this. I want to pass in the list of tags and the expected count. **And it doesn't work.**

`@Query("select b from Bookmark b left join b.tags t where t.id in ?1 group by b.id having count(*) = ?2")
Collection<Bookmark> findByTags(Collection<String> tags, int count);`

I get the following exception:

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [3] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [3] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]`

So the parameter value is correct, as I am passing in the size of the list of tags which is three as in the static example. But why does it expect a Long?

Does anybody have a clue?

Thanks!

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION:**

As JB correctly commented the following now works:

`@Query("select b from Bookmark b left join b.tags t where t.id in ?1 group by b.id having count(*) = ?2")
Collection<Bookmark> findByTags(Collection<String> tags, Long count);`

Use `java.lang.Long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message explains it. The query expects a Long, but you're passing an Integer. Change the signature to

```
findByTags(Collection<String> tags, long count);
```

Comment: Hi JB, you are right. Figured this as well. Do you know why the count would be of type Long?

Comment: Because databases can contain a shitload of data, more than 2^31 rowsthat would be the limit for an int :-)